# PHIMIND Wordpress plugin not working

Tags: wordpress

Hi i activated wordpress plugin of phimind and the reporting was working fine but after few days it automatically stopped working. i uninstalled and installed it again but nothing worked. please can you suggest to make the phimind plugin for reporting work?

Comment: HI, "plugin not working" doesn't exactly describe the issue, if someone replies they will be guessing. The first step is to check the logs, if that doesn't help enable debug mode : https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG , if that doesn't point where the problem lies, disable all the plugins except PHIMIND and see if that works. If it does enable the rest of the plugins one at a time till PHIMIND breaks and you will know the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analyticator conflicts with PhiMind, check it

also tell me the wordpress version
check other plugin conflicts